# Is there a way to auto align bootstrap 5 footers in a series of cards?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

When I try the following html code in bootstrap 5, the third column is longer than the first two columns:

```html
   <!-- bootstrap scripts -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
 
 <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Giraffes's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 rowy">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 coly">
        <div class="card">  

          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>Free</h2>
            <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
            <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
            <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <!-- w-100 100% as wide as parent -->
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary">Sign</button> 
          </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            boogle</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 coly">
        <div class="card">  

          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Labrador</h3>

          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
            <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
            <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
            <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-outline-dark">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
            boogle</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
        <div class="card">  

          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Mastiff</h3>
            
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
            <p>Pirority Listing</p>
            <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
            <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
            <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <button type="button" class="w-75 btn btn-lg btn-outline-dark">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            boogle</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My understanding is in bootstrap 4, I could use class="card-deck" and all the card would automatically have the same length.  This has been removed for bootstrap 5.  Is there anything similar in bootstrap 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HDP noted, if you just need the cards to all be the same height, than adding `h-100` to the card will accomplish that.

If you want your buttons to be in-line, then set the card-body to `d-flex flex-column` and add `flex-grow-1` to the last paragraph tag in each card body. That will push the buttons to the bottom of the card body.

```html
   <!-- bootstrap scripts -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
 
 <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Giraffes's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 rowy">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 coly">
        <div class="card h-100">  

          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h2>Free</h2>
            <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
            <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
            <p class="flex-grow-1">Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <!-- w-100 100% as wide as parent -->
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary">Sign</button> 
          </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            boogle</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 coly">
        <div class="card h-100">  

          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Labrador</h3>

          </div>
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
            <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
            <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
            <p class="flex-grow-1">Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-outline-dark">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
            boogle</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
        <div class="card h-100">  

          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Mastiff</h3>
            
          </div>
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
            <p>Pirority Listing</p>
            <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
            <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
            <p class="flex-grow-1">Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <button type="button" class="w-75 btn btn-lg btn-outline-dark">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            boogle</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add `.h-100` to the cards for equal height.

```html
   <!-- bootstrap scripts -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

 
    <h2>A Plan for Every Giraffes's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 rowy">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 coly">
        <div class="card h-100">  

          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>Free</h2>
            <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
            <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
            <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <!-- w-100 100% as wide as parent -->
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary">Sign</button> 
          </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            boogle</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 coly">
        <div class="card h-100">  

          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Labrador</h3>

          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
            <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
            <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
            <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-outline-dark">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
            boogle</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
        <div class="card h-100">  

          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Mastiff</h3>
            
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
            <p>Pirority Listing</p>
            <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
            <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
            <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <button type="button" class="w-75 btn btn-lg btn-outline-dark">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            boogle</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```